# Regex Match non greedy all character until the rest of regex matches

Tags: c#, regex

I need help about regular expression matching

I am matching items on invoices, so I want to catch all the description but stop when the end of regex matches

[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/qaKAcN/1)

My regex :
(^ (?<Desc>[\s\S]*****) (?<QtyOrder>(?:[0-9]+)) (?<QtyRecv>(?:[0-9]+)) (?<QteBO>(?:[0-9]*)) [$](?<UnitPrice>(?:[0-9]+).(?:[0-9]+))[\s]+(?:(?<Rebate>(?:[0-9]+).(?:[0-9,]+)) %)?[\s]+(?<Total>(?:[0-9]*[,]?[0-9]+).(?:[0-9]+))[\s]+[\r\n|\r|\n])

One solution but it's not general enough:

(^ (?<Desc>[\s\S]**{3,85}**) (?<QtyOrder>(?:[0-9]+)) (?<QtyRecv>(?:[0-9]+)) (?<QteBO>(?:[0-9]*)) [$](?<UnitPrice>(?:[0-9]+).(?:[0-9]+))[\s]+(?:(?<Rebate>(?:[0-9]+).(?:[0-9,]+)) %)?[\s]+(?<Total>(?:[0-9]*[,]?[0-9]+).(?:[0-9]+))[\s]+[\r\n|\r|\n])

so by limmiting the lenght of the description it will give me good results most of the time but not when the description is longer than 85 character and if I put 85 larger it will match less items.

So I need to modify the regex to o make the \s\S less greedy and stop as soon as the end of my regex matches.

How can I do that

**Solution by @Pieterjan**

The regex looks like :

(^ (?<Desc>[\s\S]***?**) (?<QtyOrder>(?:[0-9]+)) (?<QtyRecv>(?:[0-9]+)) (?<QteBO>(?:[0-9]*)) [$](?<UnitPrice>(?:[0-9]+).(?:[0-9]+))[\s]+(?:(?<Rebate>(?:[0-9]+).(?:[0-9,]+)) %)?[\s]+(?<Total>(?:[0-9]*[,]?[0-9]+).(?:[0-9]+))[\s]+[\r\n|\r|\n])

[RegexFixed](https://regex101.com/r/1Fw7mf/1)

Comment: Without seeing typical input data, that will be hard to tell. But also, I'd recommend not to use regex (alone) but maybe consider a multi step algorithm.

Comment: Are you working on _any_ invoice or one specific instance of invoices from the same source? That typically have the same structure and similar content?

Comment: @Fildor I did put the input data in the regex demo link where you have the regex and the data. I have a regex per supplier so it's a general solution, just one for the specific invoice type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-greedy regex you need to insert a question mark `?` after the selector.
For the input string:

```
<tag1>filler<tag2>
```

The following regex

```
\<.*\>
```

only results in 1 match: `<tag1>filler<tag2>`

However inserting a question mark after `.*`

```
\<.*?\>
```

yields 2 matches:

- `<tag1>`
- `<tag2>`